# how to get the function return value, when a event happen

Tags: javascript

html

```
<p id="tag_p"><p>
```

javascript

```
function a() {
    return 1;
}


document.getElementById('tag_p').addEventListener('click', a);
```

I want to get return value,

Like `let n = a();`, when click tag p.

Comment: Your event listener should do whatever work is needed, including saving any program "state".

Comment: You are trying to put the "returned value" inside the `<p>` tag>

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Where is `let n`? You haven't said, but it doesn't seem to be anywhere near anything that triggers when the event occurs.

Comment: @Quentin We should probably update that question (and provide an answer) that explicitly covers event handling. I suspect many people won't make the conceptual leap. (And maybe roll up some answers to avoid the mega-scroll.)

Comment: get return value and store it in variable?
I don't know if it's possible to do this.

Comment: maybe call a function, and it will caculate and then return the result

Comment: @TyT You're *already* calling a function and trying to return a value. The event handler needs to do whatever work is necessary; events are asynchronous. Event handler returns values indicate only whether or not the event was handled.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you, I am new to javascript. I am not fully understand.
But I still get something more.

Answer (score -1):

You can process the result *inside* the EventHandler.

```
document.querySelector('#tag_p').addEventListener('click', function(evt){ console.log( "you clicked, I got: %d",  a() );
```

This takes the result from the function "a" and outputs it as a number "%d" onto the browser console. More elaborately

```
    document.getElementById('tag_p').addEventListener('click', function(evt){ 
        let b = a();
        b++;
        b--;
console.log( "The value of A is (after +1 and -1): %d",  b );
    }
```

Comment: You should always describe your code how it works for both the OP as well as for the future readers.